# API Security for a Laravel+Nuxt.js project

Tags: laravel, api, csrf, content-security-policy, nuxt.js

I have a website which is based on a Laravel backend api and a Nuxt.js frontend app.

The laravel app is served at api.website.com. Till now the api was open, meaning everyone can make a get request. There are almost no post requests.

I know need to implement a login mechanism for the users (Usual login+register and facebook login).

My question is about how would I go to make this process secure. Do I need Laravel Passport (or other similar mechanism)?

My thought is that, say I have an endpoint api.website.com/register (POST), I do not want anyone to be able to just make a post request and create an account. I need to have some sort of security like a csrf token. I know I can use CORS but that doesn't really provide much of security in this case.

Comment: you can use Laravel passport to secure your api. 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport

Answer (score 1):

You can use jwt like [this](https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-nuxt) or laravel passport.